# MDM & MAM Framework for Enterprise distribution

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mdm

I am evaluating MDM & MAM frameworks available in the market. I have very specific requirements, some of the important ones are as below

1. The downloading of app should not depend on internet, the app can be
   hosted on  network server and downloaded from there.
2. Control device settings such as WiFi, Bluetooth, Brightness etc
3. Control installation/uninstallation of third party apps, (eg-
   tablets can only install calculator app)
4. Version based app distribution (eg- client A needs version 1.2 on 4
   tablets and version 2.0 on 10 tablets)
5. Support iOS & Android apps.
6. Push updates to certain devices(using UDID)
7. Private app store login to control roll outs for particular client
   i.e one login shared between multiple devices

So far I have considered following

1. iOS Enterprise program
2. Google play Enterprise program
3. Apperian
4. Appaloosa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have a look at this service too. It's ManageEngine. And it provides MDM and MAM as I got to read. It's better if you can have a look at the following link and think if it suits for you.
It supports, iOS, Android and Windows (both tablets and handset devices).
Here is the [link](https://www.manageengine.com/mobile-device-management/)! I'm also really interested in MDM and MAM services. And also this ManageEngine provides a full featured services free of charge for up to five devices. So you can test and check it freely.

**Its MDM provides the following features as it says:**

1. Seamlessly distributing both in-house and Store Apps to groups/devices
2. Assigning App Store Apps, Play Store Apps and enterprise Apps on the
   App Catalog of the end users' device
3. Getting the status of the deployed Apps on the users' devices
4. Removing Apps that are not required anymore

**And its MAM is giving you the capabilities to do following as it says:**

1. Managing the Apps over the Air (OTA) to groups/devices
2. Purchase and distribute apps through VPP program
3. Maintaining repository of all Apps used in the network
4. Independently user can refer and self install apps on air
5. Automatically get App information from App Store and Play Store
6. Revoke app license and reapply it to the designated devices